# remove group if any member containes NA in R

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I remove entire group if one of its values is `NA`. For ex - remove `category` B because it contains `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

tbl = tibble(category = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
             values = c(2, 3, 1, NA))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `filter` after grouping by 'category'

```
library(dplyr)
tbl %>% 
    group_by(category) %>% 
    filter(!any(is.na(values))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  category values
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 A             2
2 A             3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tbl %>% 
  filter(!category %in% category[is.na(values)])
```

**Output**

```
  category values
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 A             2
2 A             3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tbl %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  filter(all(!is.na(values)))
```

```
  category values
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 A             2
2 A             3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the  categories which has at least one `NA` value and exclude them.

```
subset(tbl, !category %in% unique(category[is.na(values)]))

#  category values
#  <chr>     <dbl>
#1 A             2
#2 A             3
```

If you prefer `dplyr::filter`.

```
library(dplyr)

tbl %>% filter(!category %in% unique(category[is.na(values)]))
```